# Unable to update $scope after executing GET call from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on Cordova-Hyrbrid app using visual studio. 
For select control, I am using plugin called ionic-model-select (http://inmagik.github.io/ionic-modal-select).

The values for select are supposed to come from webapi call. If I debug, I can see that the $scope.language is getting populated, however, select shows blank window.

I tried $scope.$apply(), and $scope.$digest() after the calls, however it does not work. Any idea why I am not getting values in select control?

angularjs code:

```
        $http.get(sharedProperties.getURLOfLanguagesWebAPI()).then(function (data) {

        allData = sharedProperties.convertXml2JSon(data.data);

        for (var i = 0; i < allData.OVRLookupData.Languages.length; i++) {
            $scope.languages.push({ "id": parseInt(allData.Languages[i].LanguageCode), "name": allData.Languages[i].Language });
        }
        $scope.$apply();
        $scope.loadingLangues = false;

    }, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

The HTML is like:

```
            <div ng-show="!loadingLangues" ng-class="{'has-error':errLan}">
            <label name="Language" class="item item-selectbox">
                <span class="input-label" style="float:left">Select Language</span>
                <button class="button button-dark button-outline icon-right ion-arrow-down-b"
                        modal-select ng-model="selectedValue"
                        options="languages"
                        on-select="languageChange(newValue)"
                        modal-title="Select Language">
                    {{ selectedValue.name || &apos;Select Language&apos;}}
                    <div class="option">{{option.name}}</div>
                </button>
            </label>
            <label ng-if="errLan" class="item">
                <span class="form-error item-text-wrap">Please select language.</span>
            </label>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/inmagik/ionic-modal-select/issues/49) that has been [fixed yesterday](https://github.com/inmagik/ionic-modal-select/pull/50).

Since neither bower package nor npm package has been updated, you need to take the source from GitHub if you want to use that functionality.

Comment: Thank you rpadovani, any ideal when this will be available in bower package? or how can I track it?

Comment: @TechTurtle sorry, I'm not involved in the project, I just took a look to the repo. You need to take an eye to `package.json` and `bower.json` [files here][0]. I also suggest you to open an issue asking for the update of the package...

[0]: https://github.com/inmagik/ionic-modal-select

Comment: After downloading the files, I was able to update $scope.